# trouble with writing data definitions

Tags: scheme, racket

I have trouble writing simple data definitions. I need to know how would you write one for the following-

So a profile consists of the user’s name, location and relationship status and a 
lof (which is a list of friends). A friend consists of a name, location and 
relationship status. How would you write data definitions and provide examples of data for 
profile, friend, and lof?

not sure if its like this

```
;; A profile is one of: 
;; - empty 
;; - (make-user name location relationship-status LOF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's exactly the "trouble" you're having with data definitions? they all are pretty straightforward, almost a direct translation of the description:

```
(define-struct profile (name location relationship-status lof))
(define-struct friend  (name location relationship-status))

(define lof
  (list
   (make-friend "Lucy" "Minneapolis" 'married)
   (make-friend "Schroeder" "Minneapolis" 'married)
   (make-friend "Patty" "Minneapolis" 'open-relationship)))

(make-profile "Charlie" "Minneapolis" 'widower lof)
```